# Opera menu text seems to be ghostly (not showing properly)

Tags: 14.04, menu, text, opera

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and when I use Opera the drop down menus are not showing the text properly, is there a way in settings or similar to fix this? Have tried in both Opera and Ubuntu but no luck.

(On a side note I noticed that when I download and install the updated Opera version, it still shows the 'Install Updates' icon)

[image]

Comment: how did you installed it and what version is your Opera?

Comment: @Redbob It's Opera 45.0.2552.898 ("Opera is up to date") and the system is  Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (x86; MATE).  I installed it via `dpkg -i`